# Angular 8 : compilation error while performing multiplication on object

Tags: angular, angular8

I am facing issue while compiling my angular code

```
  ERROR in src/app/order-details/order-details.component.html:76:55 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

76         <div class="mat-display-1">you have to pay {{(productNumber | async ) * 90  }}  $</div>
```

however I am getting the correct value on the UI.

any check can i put to remove this error.

more code

```
constructor(private http : HttpClientService) {
this.productNumber=this.http.orderDetailEmitter;
```

}

Comment: You aren't actually executing the `orderDetailEmitter` function as you're missing the parentheses.

Comment: code is running fine. its a reference of readonly orderDetailEmitter = new ReplaySubject<number>(1);

Comment: Then please update your questions to show all relevant code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting Object is possibly 'null'. in Angular template file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53942837/getting-object-is-possibly-null-in-angular-template-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're running into is a race condition.  You're subscribing to the orderDetailEmitter observable before it has a valid integer value.  This is normal.

You have two fixes that I know of.

1. Coalesce the value:

```
{{ ( (productNumber | async ) || 0 )* 90  }}
```

2. Use an ngIf

```
<div *ngIf="productNumber | async" class="mat-display-1">you have to pay {{(productNumber | async ) * 90  }}  $</div>
```

Either one of these should do the trick.

Comment: Possible option 3, don't use the angular pipe in this scenario, use a normal subscribe pattern, multiply and declare a new property to the resultant value.

Comment: Ideally, you want to avoid subscriptions, but to your point, you can handle this the RxJs way by doing the following:


this.productNumber =this.http.orderDetailEmitter.pipe(map(t=> t * 90));

Comment: Why would you want to avoid subscriptions? Just use the `Take`  implementation to manage them. Also, under the hood the async pipe is still a subscription.

Comment: It's best to have the UI handle it ... this is literally why the Angular gods created the | async pipe.  Why would you want to write extra code?

Also, with your ````Take```` approach, what happens when the value changes?